# Можно ли использовать php для написания бота дискорд?

Tags: php, discord

Вопрос знатокам, почему боты на discord рекомендуют не писать на php?
И нормально ли использовать php для постоянного соединения со шлюзами в фоновом режиме?
Слышал, что иногда работает не корректно.

Comment: Можно, разрешаем

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Конечно можно, есть большое количество хороших библиотек на PHP для работы с Discord.  А про постоянное соединение можно подробнее, какая цель?

Comment: Да все корректно работает, пишите на здоровье. Но определитесь какие задачи этот бот выполняют, вероятно уже для этих задач php - плохое решение.